# Cannot hover whole row at once

Tags: html, css, hover, row

I'm trying to create a copy of a website I thought was interesting. However I'm running into some problems trying to highlight the whole row at once, without highlighting others. I've created a table of divs however when I try to select a single row such as with class .row:hover im unable to select anything(hovering mouse should change color). I've tried multiple combination and google searches such as .row:hover column names, however this selects every row not just the one I want. I cant seem to figure out this behavior would appreciate any help.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/u31h4n5y/
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  width: 63vw;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(123, 108, 160);
}

.row {
  height: 125px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.one {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

.two {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0px;
}

.three {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
}

.four {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.row:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>WEB
  <h1>
    <h2>Hey everyone</h2>
    <div id="header"> </div>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="one">
          <p>Week 1</br> May 7 <br> - <br> May 11 </p>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
          <ul>
            <li> Course introduction </li>
            <li> Internet Architecture </li>
            <li> Introduction to Javascript </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
          <a href=""> Welcome </a>
          <a href="">Lecture 1 </a>
        </div>

        <div class="four">
          <h3> Work Due </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="one">
            <p> Week 2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="two">
            <ul>
              <li> Javascript functions </li>
              <li> Built in Global Functions </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="three">
            <a href=""> Lecture 2 </a>
          </div>
          <div class="four"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="one"></div>
          <div class="two"></div>
          <div class="three"></div>
          <div class="four"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="special"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: you have written .row:hover background red and same in the .row...you should change it and post here final code you are looking answer for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because the background is not defined on the `.row` element but its child element, so you need to target the child. You may simply do this;

```
.row:hover > div{   
   background-color:red;
}
```

Full code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  width: 63vw;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(123, 108, 160);
}

.row {
  height: 125px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.one {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

.two {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0px;
}

.three {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
}

.four {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.row:hover>div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>WEB</h1>
<h2>Hey everyone</h2>
<div id="header"> </div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one">
      <p>Week 1<br> May 7 <br> - <br> May 11
        <p/>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <ul>
        <li> Course introduction </li>
        <li> Internet Architecture </li>
        <li> Introduction to Javascript </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <a href=""> Welcome </a>
      <a href="">Lecture 1 </a>
    </div>

    <div class="four">
      <h3> Work Due </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one">
      <p> Week 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <ul>
        <li> Javascript functions </li>
        <li> Built in Global Functions </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <a href=""> Lecture 2 </a>
    </div>
    <div class="four"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="four"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="special"></div>
```

Comment: great answer, initially it wasnt working properly for me but I see you also closed the first div I missed.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely work

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  width: 63vw;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(123, 108, 160);
}

.row {
  height: 125px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.one {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

.two {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0px;
}

.three {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
}

.four {
  border: none;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.row:hover div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h1>WEB</h1>
<h2>Hey everyone</h2>
<div id="header"> </div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one">
      <p>Week 1<br> May 7 <br> - <br> May 11
        <p/>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <ul>
        <li> Course introduction </li>
        <li> Internet Architecture </li>
        <li> Introduction to Javascript </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <a href=""> Welcome </a>
      <a href="">Lecture 1 </a>
    </div>

    <div class="four">
      <h3> Work Due </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one">
      <p> Week 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <ul>
        <li> Javascript functions </li>
        <li> Built in Global Functions </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <a href=""> Lecture 2 </a>
    </div>
    <div class="four"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="four"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="special"></div>

</html>
```

In you css part, just change a little bit of your .row:hover to

```
.row:hover div {
      background-color:red;
    }
```

.row:hover as when you hover it, you want to manipulate div tag, so add div tag in .row:hover and do the css part for div tag.
you can also add any another tag/class/ID and then manipulate them in the .row:hover